# Central Limit Theorem - Wikipedia article

Tags: proof-explanation, self-learning, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to follow the CLT proof of [Wikipedia's article on CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)

[image]

I can follow up to and including the part that $Z_{n} \to N(0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$.

I cannot understand the very last sentence of the proof. How do I go from the distribution of $Z_{n}=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n - n \mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}}=\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i})-n\mu }{\sqrt{n \sigma ^{2} }} \sim N(0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$ to the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} \sim N(n\mu, n\sigma^{2}) $ to the distribution of $\bar{X}\sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n})$ ?

Comment: That last sentence should be removed from Wikipedia. It is not correct, also , the statement of CLT has nothing to do with that sentence. The proof was finished in the sentence before that one. Indeed, notice that the statement of CLT just involves convergence in distribution to $N(0,1)$.

Comment: I would personally also remove the second sentence of the proof, since this proof does not seem similar to the weak law of Large Numbers proof (weak LLN uses the Markov/Chebyshev inequality and involves a different kind of convergence).

Comment: But how does the fact that $Z_{n}=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n - n \mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}} \sim N(0,1)$ prove that  the mean is normally distributed?

Comment: As I said, the last sentence should be removed.  The CLT is not making a statement about the mean (and certainly not making a statement about the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$).  By arithmetic it is true that $Z_n = \sqrt{\frac{n}{\sigma^2}}(\overline{X}_n-\mu)$ implies $\overline{X}_n = \frac{\sigma Z_n}{\sqrt{n}} + \mu$.  If you want, you can say that since $Z_n$ is approximately Gaussian $N(0,1)$, then $\frac{\sigma Z_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is approximately Gaussian $N(0, \sigma^2/n)$. Note that it does not make sense for a function of $n$ to converge (as $n\rightarrow \infty$) to another function of $n$.